# Обособлять ли оборот "при ..."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Дорогие друзья, есть предложение:

> Твердые смазочные материалы работают в условиях температур от -200 до +600 ºС (,) при контактных давлениях до 2500 МПа и демонстрируют низкий коэффициент трения до 0,03 при медленном скольжении до 0,5 м/с.

А теперь вопрос: нужна ли запятая перед дополнительной информацией с предлогом "ПРИ"? Или, может быть, здесь нужны две запятые? Лично мне кажется, что ни одной, но хотелось бы услышать еще чье-нибудь мнение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понять мысль автора. Он говорит об условиях, в которых работают материалы, а это совокупность температур и давлений (данные температуры при данных давлениях). Запятые не нужны.

Далее, материалы демонстрируют некий показатель в некоторых условиях (демонстрируют низкий коэффициент при медленном скольжении). Запятые не нужны.

А вот показатели *0,03* и *0,5 м/с* — это уточнение. Они должны обособляться, я бы заключил их в скобки.

**Твердые смазочные материалы работают в условиях температур от -200 до +600 ºС  при контактных давлениях до 2500 МПа и демонстрируют низкий коэффициент трения (до 0,03) при медленном скольжении (до 0,5 м/с).**